# I need to convert a list; which will be provided through input, hence it will become a string; back into a list

Tags: python, string, list, eval, undefined

As said in the title of the thread.
Also I tried using `eval()` for these lists I'll be inputting, but these lists contain string elements and other (sub-?) lists, e.g:

```
[Pacific, [-45,30,25], [120,59, 15]]
```

When providing such input `eval()` responds perfectly fine for numbers-only lists but when applied to strings sends back a `NameError` for these string elements saying they are not defined.

Comment: If you're using `eval`, you'll also need to quote your strings, just like you would in code.

Comment: Also, please use `ast.literal_eval` instead of eval...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to be inputting your strings within quotations, ie,

```
["Pacific", [-45,30,25], [120,59, 15]]
```

when you input it just as `Pacific`, python's `eval()` function will look for a variable named `Pacific`, hence the NameError you have been getting

Comment: no prob! if this answered your question, please give it a green checkmark or an upvote ^^

Comment: Perhaps you can warn him of the [dangers of `eval`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) and point him at Use `ast.literal_eval`. See http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: `eval()` is only dangerous for untrusted input, if you read his post you'll see that he states that he will be inputting the lists himself, so as long as OP trusts himself.......

Answer (score 0):

Your original input string is perfectly valid [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) string, which is a safe, powerful and -at least in my view- easy way to serialize and de-serialize data structures. In order to read (or save) YAML strings you might want to get PyYAML:

```
sudo pip install pyyaml
```

Then, you can perfectly run the following code in order to read your data into Python:

```
from yaml import load
pacific = load('[Pacific, [-45,30,25], [120,59, 15]]')
```